# "Cant fight no more", is this grammatically correct?

Tags: american-english, british-english, negative-concord

"Cant fight no more", is this grammatically correct?
If not, what is the correct way of saying this?

Comment: Is that a misspelling, or did you really mean "[cant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cant?s=t)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double negative isn’t grammatical in Standard English, but it is in other dialects. To be grammatical in Standard English it would have to be ‘Can’t fight any more.’

Comment: To be "grammatical", it should probably include a *subject*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Aye, I.

Comment: Use "can't fight any more" or "can fight no more"; both OK as single negatives.